# how to make installer of a web app in angular,mysql , php, and node

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs, node.js, installation

I have created a application that uses angularjs and php and nodejs as backend and redis as a caching server, now i want to create a installer that can package the installation of php mysql and nodejs and of my angularjs code in one application and run it in localhost how  can i do that.

Comment: You should consider explain a little more what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

There is no defined tool for such a process. But out of the box you may use a docker container or npm pkg module which you can bundle your node backend server and the angular into a exe or platform independent bundle.

But pkg module cannot be used to bundle the php (But you may able to use php executable externally).

Check out these links

- [Docker](https://www.docker.com/)
- [pkg](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pkg)

Anyway this is not a simple process, will be lot of overheads since the toolbox that you are using is not built for what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thank you very much Janith.